# Двуязычные дети - словосочетания относительных прилагательных с существительными

Tags: словосочетание

Добрый вечер, у меня такой вопрос: двуязычные дети в германии (русский 1-й родной, немецкий с 2-х лет)образовывают сложные слова типа: чайная ложка, детская коляска, шариковая ручка, зубная щетка не всегда с помощью относительноги прилагательного, а просто одним существительным: ложка, коляска, ручка, щетка. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне об\яснить этот феномен? Я вот думаю в сторону свободных/ несвободных словосочетаний...

Спасибо заранее. Юлия

Comment: или детки просто говорят: ложка для чая, коляска для бебиков, щетка для зубов...

Answer (score 4):

Чайная ложка - ложка для чая, щетка для зубов - зубная щетка - это примеры грамматических синонимов. Варианты равноправны. Напомнило задание В1 в ГИА: замените синонимичным словосочетанием. Интересно, а как они заменяют словосочетание "шариковая ручка"? Наверное, говорят просто "ручка", так и наши так говорят. Многие и не знают, что она "шариковая", потому что не знают противоположного - перьевая. Кстати, и детскую коляску называем просто "коляска", потому что дома других, к счастью, нет.